# imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); not working for ImageView

Tags: java, android

- I am trying to implement `imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` if my `URL` is `null` then the visibility of the `imageView` should ne `GONE` or else it should be `VISIBLE`.
- In my `XML` I have defined it as `android:visibility="gone"` and if the `URL` is not `null` then I am displaying the `image`.
- The issue here is, it displays the image when it contains the url. But when the `url` is `null` it is giving the empty space.
- XML

```
<ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/rectanglebutton"/>
```

- Java

```
url = list.get(position).getImageUrl();
            if(url == "null") {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.requestLayout();
            }
            else
            {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.requestLayout();
                Glide
                        .with(DisplayQuestions.this)
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageView);
            }
```

Comment: please, first verify the url content `Log.i("URL",url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be in the java code.

try changing

```
if (url == "null")
```

to

```
if (url == null)
```

- null should not be in doubble quotes.
- and generally you should use `"some_string".equals(object)` to test strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check url string if its empty

```
if(url.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
   imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   imageView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` in case the URL is really `null`, which the question seems to want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = list.get(position).getImageUrl();
            if(url == null) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.requestLayout();
            }
            else
            {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.requestLayout();
                Glide
                        .with(DisplayQuestions.this)
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageView);
            }
```

null should not be inside double quote